# MYSQL - Showing status input as it's own column

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble writing a SQL query to show the status of a row as it's own column as shown in the picture.

[image]

I was thinking of using an alias for Status as:

`SELECT 'Table A.Date', 'Table A.Status' as ... FROM Table A;`

But this doesn't resolve the issue on how to display each status type as their own column and number value.

Can someone point out how to do this?

Comment: Are these the only possible values of `Status` field? If so, Google for *conditional aggregation*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. I used `CASE` statement to conditionally count the status as one depending on the status type given.

```
SELECT 
      Date,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Status='Pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)Pending,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Status='Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)Completed,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Status='Cancelled' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)Cancelled
FROM Table A 
WHERE Date='2014-01-01'
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: Thanks tried this and it works, changed out `WHERE` with `HAVING` as I believe you can't use `WHERE` with `GROUP BY`. However not sure where they are getting the 10 from as the value.

Comment: My query is wrong, WHERE should be first in the query before GROUP BY. I've edited it already. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select A.date,
    count(
        case
            when A.Status='Pending'
            Then 1
            Else NULL
        End
    ) as Pending,
    count(
        case
            when A.Status='Completed'
            Then 1
            Else NULL
        End
    ) as Completed,
    count(
        case
            when A.Status='Cancelled'
            Then 1
            Else NULL
        End
    ) as Cancelled
    From A
    group by A.date
```